# DC MOTOR + ENCODER + PYTHON

Tags: ros, python, encoder, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone.
I have the next equipment:
https://www.pololu.com/product/2598 ,
https://www.pololu.com/product/2208
and raspberry pi.

I want to control the dc motors via ROS and Python. Is it possible? I can't find some good example or tutorials. I will be so appreciated if you will help me.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245514/dc-motor-+-encoder-+-python/) by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-21**:
did you solve your problem?

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-11-21**:
did you solve the problem @Tvlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a small robot that uses similar Pololu motors with ROS. A few considerations:

- You might want motors with a lower gear ratio. Depending on the size of your robot, and how fast you want to move, you might want to consider the 210:1 or 150:1 motors. Also depends on your wheel size, of course.
- You'll want wheel encoders, such as [these Hall-effect encoders from Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/3081).

For my robot I use the ROS package `ros_arduino_bridge` for both the Arduino code and the Python ROS controller node. It's unclear whether you intent to have a microcontroller for the motors. I'm using a Pololu A-Star connected to a Raspberry Pi running ROS. If you were to use an A-Star, [Marco Werther's fork](https://github.com/mw46d/ros_arduino_bridge) has support for the A-Star motor controller.

If you provide some more details about the rest of your hardware, I could provide more suggestions for a controller or ROS nodes you might want.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on 2016-10-13**:
Dear Mark.Thank you for your feedback.
The hardware is easy:
Raspberry PI3 + 2 DC  motor and encoders + Line follower.
Line follower link is : https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13582?_ga=1.13538103.1258904486.1476366311
I will be so appreciated if you will help me.
Thank you very much.
Best Regards

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-10-13**:
You may find it useful to have an Arduino-class microcontroller for doing low-level PID control, etc., rather than doing it on the Pi. Also, the line follower array you've chosen is a 5V device, so you'll have to either talk to it from an Arduino to use level shifters.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-10-13**:
The Pololu A-Star (https://www.pololu.com/product/3117) plugs in to the Pi GPIO bus, and has a voltage regulator that can take a variety of battery voltages, and will power the Pi, too. It has on-board H-bridges to run the motors off the battery power.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-10-13**:
You can, instead, control everything from the RPi, but you will need a voltage regulator and level shifters. Since you don't have any distance sensors, you won't be able to use the ROS navigation stack. Instead, write your own node to do line following.

**Comment by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on 2016-10-13**:
Thanks for your answer. So, in this case, I can't create few nodes and just tell to dc motors the distance(use Python...rospy)?

**Comment by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on 2016-10-17**:
Dear Mark, You was right. I use the motor driver for system, but I can't understand how to work with encoder. Can you help me with these?